# I don't understand why i get difference answer by change put line if on in code

Tags: python

I would write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`
will print out `'beggh'`.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
result = ''
word ='a'
sen = ''
for alpha in s:
  if alpha < word:
        word ='a'
        sen = ''   
  if alpha >= word:   
        word = alpha
        sen += alpha
        if len(result) <len(sen):
            result = sen

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: '+ result)
```

Answer is

```
Logest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh
```

But just put code on different line. I got a wrong answer!!!

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
result = ''
word ='a'
sen = ''
for alpha in s:  
  if alpha >= word:   
       word = alpha
       sen += alpha
       if len(result) <len(sen):
           result = sen
  if alpha < word:
     word ='a'
     sen = '' 
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: '+ result)
```

Answer

```
Longest substring in alphabetical order is: eggh
```

The problem drive me mad!!!

Comment: If `alpha < word` is True, then you set `word = 'a'`. Conseqently, `alpha >= word` will also be True. But that isn't the case if you swap the two `if`s, so you end up skipping the first character.

Comment: oh thank you guy!!! I get it!!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937076/python-word-counter for some working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's say you got a couple of functions f1 and f2 and you're tracking every iteration of your for loop like this:

```
def f1(s):
    result = ''
    word = 'a'
    sen = ''
    for index, alpha in enumerate(s):
        if alpha < word:
            word = 'a'
            sen = ''
        if alpha >= word:
            word = alpha
            sen += alpha
            if len(result) < len(sen):
                result = sen

        print("{0}-{1} => {2}".format(index, alpha, result))

    return result


def f2(s):
    result = ''
    word = 'a'
    sen = ''
    for index, alpha in enumerate(s):
        if alpha >= word:
            word = alpha
            sen += alpha
            if len(result) < len(sen):
                result = sen
        if alpha < word:
            word = 'a'
            sen = ''

        print("{0}-{1} => {2}".format(index, alpha, result))

    return result

s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
print('-' * 80)
print('f1: Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + f1(s))
print('-' * 80)
print('f2: Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + f2(s))
```

Now, running this script would produce:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0-a => a
1-z => az
2-c => az
3-b => az
4-o => az
5-b => az
6-o => az
7-b => az
8-e => az
9-g => beg
10-g => begg
11-h => beggh
12-a => beggh
13-k => beggh
14-l => beggh
f1: Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0-a => a
1-z => az
2-c => az
3-b => az
4-o => az
5-b => az
6-o => az
7-b => az
8-e => az
9-g => az
10-g => egg
11-h => eggh
12-a => eggh
13-k => eggh
14-l => eggh
f2: Longest substring in alphabetical order is: eggh
```

As you can see, everything is the same till it reaches the iteration 9, with f1 result becomes `9-g => beg` while with f2 becomes `9-g => az`, that's how the change of order is affecting to the result, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You are discarding the first character of the new sequence

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
result = ''
word ='a'
sen = ''
for alpha in s:  
  print alpha,word,sen
  if alpha >= word:   
       word = alpha
       sen += alpha
       if len(result) <len(sen):
           result = sen
  if alpha < word:
     word = alpha
     sen = alpha 
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: '+ result)
```

notice the change:

```
  if alpha < word:
     word = alpha
     sen = alpha
```

you should save the first character of the new sequence