# beginner python program assistance

Tags: python, loops

Code is supposed to return the longest string of characters in alphabetical order. For this string it should be 'beggh'. I need help identifying the problem.

edit: the answer approved on the duplicate did not work. I'm not sure if this is because this is in python 3 and not 2 or what. The old code is below mine.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
temp_s = ''
startingChar = 0
currentChar = 0
endingChar = 1

for x in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[endingChar] >= s[currentChar]:
        temp_s = s[startingChar:endingChar+1]
        endingChar += 1
        currentChar += 1
    else:
        startingChar += 1
        endingChar += 1
        currentChar += 1
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ', temp_s)
```

This is the old code:

```
s = input('enter characters: ')
longest = s[0]
current = s[0]
for c in s[1:]:
    if c >= current[-1]:
        current += c
    else:
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current
        current = c
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is:'), longest
```

Comment: You can think of any string as being composed of a number of smaller, alphabetically sorted substrings, occurring back to back. A simple approach is to find all such substrings as you move along the string, and identify the longest one.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937076/python-word-counter

Answer (score -2):

I think ord() might be of some help to you here.

For example ord('a') = 97. To make 'a' have the first value consider using ord('a') - 96. Getting the value of 'b' would be similar, ie. ord('b') - 96.

Then iterate through your string checking if the ord() of the next value in the string is equal to or one greater than your previous value.

Comment: You don't need `ord()` you can compare characters directly, e.g. `'b' >= 'a' == True`